# Flutter notification when firestore collection changes (Background)

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

How does one notify a user when a subscribed collection (firestore) changes when the app is not open?

I'm thinking that perhaps a FCM push should be used once the collection (or a document in the collection) changes but would first investigate alternative routes.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ihave done this already but if u force close the app then it will not show u notification >>>https://medium.com/@rajeshjr/flutter-firestore-push-notification-on-data-change-youtube-style-subscribing-notifications-one-to-b09654db19e0

Answer (score 5):

You could use a Cloud Function that would run in the back-end. It would be triggered when a document in a Firestore collection is updated and sends a Firebase Cloud Messaging notification.

You will find a Cloud Function sample that shows how to send an FCM notification here: https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/fcm-notifications and the Firebase FCM documentation here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options

You will find the documentation for Firestore triggers for Cloud Functions here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events